# How to get the objectId from NSArray from PFquery in PARSE.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

My PFQuery returns the following description.I am trying to fetch the objectId of the class 
`YouQuestions`.For eg: in the below description `Ovx3B1TnaC` is the objectId for the first index of quesAray. But I have no idea on how to fetch it.

```
Printing description of quesArray:
<__NSArrayM 0xe1198f0>(
<YouQuestions:OVx3BlTnaC:(null)> {
    askedUser = "<PFUser:XGvZsNyg9p>";
    attachedImage = "<PFFile: 0xb4c9d20>";
    category = Business;
    geoLocation = "<PFGeoPoint: 0xb4c9ea0>";
    question = "Who is kaka?";
    thumbImage = "<PFFile: 0xb4c9dd0>";
},
```

This is how I did but returned nil

`PFQuery *fetchTimeLine = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YouQuestions"];
        [fetchTimeLine whereKeyExists:@"objectId"];`
`[fetchTimeLine findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *quesArray, NSError *error)
       {`


           `for (int i =0; i<quesArray.count; i++)
           { 
               PFObject *obj  = [quesArray[i] objectForKey:@"objectId"];
                [searchobjectIDsArray addObject:obj.objectId];
           } 
}];`

**EDIT:**

I fixed it like this

`for (PFObject *object in quesArray) {
     NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the array of ids:

`NSArray *oids = [quesArray valueForKeyPath:@"objectId"];`

Comment: Your answer eliminate my unwanted for loop :D